# Intellij imports a wrong class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to link to a third-party library (in a jar file) in Intellij Community 2019.1.
When I build and run my project it ends up crashing at runtime with a message:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError".
```

What happens is the mentioned library has two dependencies, let's call them A.jar and B.jar. Both of them provide a class named "Foo" with the same package path, like `acme.com.util.Foo.`

The problem is that the Foo class from A.jar implements a method `test(Class1 c)`, but the same class from package B.jar implements a method `test(Class2 c)`.

The code (of the third-party library) has following call signature:

```
import acme.com.util
Class1 c = new Class1();
foo.test(c)
```

So theoretically IntelliJ should resolve it to package A.jar, but instead the code is compiled so that at run-time it calls `test(Class2 c)` from package B.jar. When I Ctrl-click on the method of `foo.test(c)` it also takes me to the implementation of Foo inside the B.jar.
I tried to use different compilers in IntellJ (both Javac or Eclipse), with the same result.

Interesting, that when I use Eclipse IDE, the problem doesn't happen.
I wonder how it can be fixed or maybe there is a way to guide IntelliJ to pick the right package?

Comment: YOU as developer are the one who decides which class is imported. IntelliJ can make suggestions, but once you choose option A, Intellij will, when errors are encountered, assume you knew what you wanted when you chose for option A, and won't look in the second class whether it makes sense for that one.

Comment: When I import the third-party library (which in turn depends on A.jar and B.jar) how can I choose which class to import? Also the third-party library makes use of both A and B in various places, it's just in this place in their code a wrong method from a wrong class was imported.

Comment: the one class that is loaded first from the classpath will be loaded. you can't have both of them in the classpath, how should JRE choose which to use when? this is not a problem with Intellij

Comment: there are 3 ways to approach this problem that I can see. either specify the classpath on your own, or exclude the dependency that you dont need if you can. or use osgi, but that a long shot